# Ionic v4 Page Zoom via viewport meta tag

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, meta-tags

I have a website built using Ionic v4. My index.html is updated to allow user scaling

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=12.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

Pinch and zoom doesn't work in Chrome on Android.

Link to site [here](https://canada.d.qlkt.ag/lp/a19cb4e0-e673-11e9-a4e9-7de49da73c42/99e91540-8110-11e9-9e56-e5a56824737b/p/page-1)

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the small zoom applied by many smartphones by setting the initial scale and minimum-scale values to 0.86. The result is horizontal scroll is suppressed in any orientation and the user can zoom in if they want to.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.86, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=0.86">
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution for zooming on Android? I am facing the similar issue.